# Datetime from timestamp in locale time

Tags: php, date, cakephp

Please see the code:

Core.php

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

Controller

```
$value = "2014-04-12 07:41:41"
echo date("d M Y - d:i:s", strtotime($value));
```

Output

```
12 Apr 2014 - 12:41:41
```

It should be `12 Apr 2014 - 07:41:41`

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `d` instead of `h` for the hour so you're getting the day instead:

```
echo date("d M Y - d:i:s", strtotime($value));
                 ^^^^^
                 HERE
```

it should be:

```
echo date("d M Y - h:i:s", strtotime($value));
```

Answer (score 0):

echo date(d M Y - h:i:s):
you get the result as you want.